# p-Group satisfying the minimal condition on abelian subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, p-groups

Are there examples of $p$-groups satisfying the minimal condition on abelian subgroups but do not satisfy the minimal condition?

Obviously such a group cannot be locally finite.

Comment: Cross-posted to MathOF: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253530/